# Create SQL user in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, databricks-community-edition

Is there a way to create a database (sql) user (analogous to an Oracle or MySql user) in Databricks?  It doesn't seem possible in the Community edition.

[image]

For a long list of reasons... I have a need to create a very large number of tables and would like to be able to organize them by project.  If I can't create a sql user, is there another way to create what essentially amounts to different namespaces for the different projects?

I'd like to end up with something like:

project_01
schema_01
table_x
table_y
table_z
schema_02
table_a
table_b
table_x
scheam_03
table_foo
table_a
table_b
project_02
schema_01
table_d
table_e
table_f
schema_02
table_p
table_q
table_r
scheam_03
table_foo
table_bar
table_bat

So I can do something like this:

```
select * from project_01.schema_01.table_x;
select * from project_02.schema_01.table_d;
```

(each of the tables would be a different table, i.e. project_01.table_x is a separate table from project_02.table_x).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's supported by community edition, but normal deployments have [SCIM API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/scim/scim-users.html) to let you create dedicated users for [JDBC connectivity](https://docs.databricks.com/integrations/bi/jdbc-odbc-bi.html#username-and-password). The community edition is not meant to be used for any other purposes than exploration.